# Error when deploying AWS CDK stack when using 'cdk deploy'

Tags: c#, aws-cdk

Initially I thought this was related to having spaces in my user folder (the actual user is `Firstname Lastname` not just `Firstname`, but I have a symlink for my user folder which does not have spaces in it and I've updated my environment variables to look in the symlink folder, not the original one. I ran the command with a --verbose flag and found out that the error occurs when trying to run the command found in `cdk.json`: `dotnet run --project src/MyCdkCodepipeline/MyCdkCodepipeline.csproj`

This is a brand new project where all I've done is run `cdk init app --language csharp`.

I'm using:
Node version 20.10.0
Npm version 8.19.4
Cdk version 2.132.1 (build 9df7dd3)
Aws cli veriosn aws-cli/2.4.7 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

The stack trace when running the command `cdk deploy`:

```
Unhandled exception. Amazon.JSII.Runtime.JsiiError: Child process exited unexpectedly!
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Runtime.ReadResponse()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.ReceiveResponse[TResponse]()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.Hello()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.ServiceContainer.BuildServiceProvider(ILoggerFactory loggerFactoryOverride)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.ServiceContainer.<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.ServiceContainer.get_ServiceProvider()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.JsiiTypeAttributeBase.Load(Assembly assembly)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.JsiiTypeAttributeBase.Load(Assembly assembly)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Constructs.Construct..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Amazon.CDK.Stage..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Amazon.CDK.App..ctor(IAppProps props)
   at NhomeCdkCodepipeline.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Git\NEMS\nems-home\NhomeCdkCodepipeline\src\NhomeCdkCodepipeline\Program.cs:line 12
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Firstname'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.10.0

Subprocess exited with error 3762504530
```

Comment: Which environment variables did you update? Have you tried deploying from a folder with no spaces in the path?

Comment: @gshpychka I have set each environment variable that was previously `C:\Users\Firstname Lastname` to `C:\Users\FirstnameLastname`. This was done previously to starting this project I'm trying to deploy. The folder the project is in and where the C# file for the AWS stack is already in a folder with no spaces in the path.

Comment: I meant the entire path with no spaces.